# Link open my app or go to store with parameter

Tags: xamarin, deeplink

I am a Xamarin Forms developer.

I would like to open my app or go to the store with a link. And is it possible, if it is to store, after downloading my application, pass a parameter to my app?

I don't know if i was clear.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Google and Apple offer refer tracking (also called mobile conversion tracking: MCT) so you can track where the install link came from, is that what you are looking for? If so Google Analytics has a MCT program you can enroll in, they have supporting docs, implementation guides, etc...

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a parameter? as an referral code. i would like
retrieve the referral code, the code would be in the link.

Comment: Yes, the link is available. I.E. If you are using Google Play to distro your app there is the "Google Play Install Referrer API" where you can query for the referrer URL, the time that the referrer clicked the link and when the install started....

Comment: Hi, do you manage to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yandex AppMetrica offers such a feature, while having a nice xamarin.forms sdk.   https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/

Your direct case:
https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/mobile-tracking/concepts/tracking.html
 [image]

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a parameter? as an referral code. i would like
retrieve the referral code, the code would be in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase dynamic links to achieve the same thing. [here](https://doumer.me/firebase-dynamic-links-with-xamarin-forms-and-net-backend/) is an article regarding implementing firebase dynamic links with Xamarin forms.